# Fitting a GEV for annual precipitation data in R

Tags: r

I am working with annual maxima for precipitation and would like to use a GEV to fit my data. While I was able to do this, I was uncertain whether the GEV analysis in R was detecting how I assigned my block maxima. Ideally, I want to divide my 14-year time series into two 7-year blocks (i.e. Year 1 to Year 7, and then Year 8 to Year 14) using the block maxima approach. I also have 9 datasets, so I pooled my maxima for each of the 9 datasets. For example, I pooled the data by grouping all of the annual maxima for Year 1 to Year 14, producing 126 annual maxima for the 14 years:

```
library(extRemes)

#Obtaining annual maxima from the 9 datasets

Gmax <- sapply(unstack(subset), function(r){max(values(r))}) 
Gmax1 <- sapply(unstack(subset5), function(r){max(values(r))})
Gmax2 <- sapply(unstack(subset8), function(r){max(values(r))})
Gmax3 <- sapply(unstack(subset11), function(r){max(values(r))})
Gmax4 <- sapply(unstack(subset15), function(r){max(values(r))})
Gmax5 <- sapply(unstack(subset18), function(r){max(values(r))})
Gmax6 <- sapply(unstack(subset21), function(r){max(values(r))})
Gmax7 <- sapply(unstack(subset25), function(r){max(values(r))})
Gmax8 <- sapply(unstack(subset27), function(r){max(values(r))})

#Indexing to select all of the annual maxima for the 14 years for the 9 datasets (126 maxima)

Gcomb <- c(Gmax[1], Gmax1[1], Gmax2[1], Gmax3[1], Gmax4[1], Gmax5[1], Gmax6[1], Gmax7[1], Gmax8[1],
Gmax[2], Gmax1[2], Gmax2[2], Gmax3[2], Gmax4[2], Gmax5[2], Gmax6[2], Gmax7[2], Gmax8[2], Gmax[3],  
Gmax1[3], Gmax2[3], Gmax3[3], Gmax4[3], Gmax5[3], Gmax6[3], Gmax7[3], Gmax8[3], Gmax[4], Gmax1[4], 
Gmax2[4], Gmax3[4], Gmax4[4], Gmax5[4], Gmax6[4], Gmax7[4], Gmax8[4], Gmax[5], Gmax1[5], Gmax2[5], 
Gmax3[5], Gmax4[5], Gmax5[5], Gmax6[5], Gmax7[5], Gmax8[5], Gmax[6], Gmax1[6], Gmax2[6], Gmax3[6], 
Gmax4[6], Gmax5[6], Gmax6[6], Gmax7[6], Gmax8[6], Gmax[7], Gmax1[7], Gmax2[7], Gmax3[7], Gmax4[7], 
Gmax5[7], Gmax6[7], Gmax7[7], Gmax8[7], Gcomb1<-c(Gmax[8], Gmax1[8], Gmax2[8], Gmax3[8], Gmax4[8], 
Gmax5[8], Gmax6[8], Gmax7[8], Gmax8[8], Gmax[9], Gmax1[9], Gmax2[9], Gmax3[9], Gmax4[9], Gmax5[9], 
Gmax6[9], Gmax7[9], Gmax8[9], Gmax[10], Gmax1[10], Gmax2[10], Gmax3[10], Gmax4[10], Gmax5[10], 
Gmax6[10], Gmax7[10], Gmax8[10], Gmax[11], Gmax1[11], Gmax2[11], Gmax3[11], Gmax4[11], Gmax5[11], 
Gmax6[11], Gmax7[11], Gmax8[11], Gmax[12], Gmax1[12], Gmax2[12], Gmax3[12], Gmax4[12], Gmax5[12], 
Gmax6[12], Gmax7[12], Gmax8[12], Gmax[13], Gmax1[13], Gmax2[13], Gmax3[13], Gmax4[13], Gmax5[13], 
Gmax6[13], Gmax7[13], Gmax8[13], Gmax[14], Gmax1[14], Gmax2[14], Gmax3[14], Gmax4[14], Gmax5[14], 
Gmax6[14], Gmax7[14], Gmax8[14]))

> Gcomb

[1] 285.9906 159.0246 216.1329 317.3168 134.0706 240.5591 143.3593 278.6423 300.2213 287.6668 
133.6294 235.7827 348.0946 133.2577
[15] 200.7394 142.7288 255.3043 332.2073 276.2251 153.0331 218.5597 320.7929 123.5906 215.9244 
165.5872 386.4905 259.4115 247.1718
[29] 160.4190 276.9192 313.5304 175.7406 211.9053 132.6234 318.1059 297.1881 254.9781 148.2776 
270.5989 292.8830 155.7216 194.3641
[43] 126.4537 236.9236 383.5452 308.1921 142.6571 244.4956 356.3880 160.6649 243.4610 154.6999 
244.6703 349.7785 234.6858 172.3195
[57] 275.7311 359.1511 115.8130 185.3560 180.2979 210.3161 302.0780 235.7213 157.7454 262.2424 
307.9303 136.0832 224.9627 146.9899
[71] 297.2613 337.8194 242.0865 148.3942 205.8541 342.4027 153.2334 191.5551 137.0983 367.9224     
428.6493 247.1022 165.9219 247.4879
[85] 327.0393 146.6705 202.0553 146.3462 254.7741 346.1007 233.6528 139.6812 317.0052 336.3853 
155.3950 219.7212 144.6838 284.4246
[99] 306.7610 243.9972 140.4338 267.6197 366.8654 159.3714 182.8306 136.9110 284.0912 362.1337 
297.6855 161.9404 395.7047 402.7022
[113] 128.2466 218.4132 135.6528 320.8012 308.9064 264.3488 136.1558 285.4910 324.7307 177.1121 
226.3639 138.8371 280.7834 370.2415

#Fitting a GEV

superfit <- fevd(x=Gcomb, type="GEV")

fevd(x = Gcomb, type = "GEV")

[1] "Estimation Method used: MLE"


Negative Log-Likelihood Value:  727.0276 


Estimated parameters:
location       scale       shape 
206.1101087  72.3405803  -0.1773972 

Standard Error Estimates:
 location     scale     shape 
7.8269021 6.0762930 0.1016432 

Estimated parameter covariance matrix.
         location      scale       shape
location 61.2603966 16.5091185 -0.42074406
scale    16.5091185 36.9213365 -0.41062737
shape    -0.4207441 -0.4106274  0.01033135

AIC = 1460.055 

BIC = 1468.564
```

This output is based on my entire time series. My question is how does R know that I am making 7-year blocks (i.e. Year 1 to Year 7, and the Year 8 to Year 14)?

Thank you, and any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: the `extRemes` library includes discussion of blocks supplied to `fevd` in the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/extRemes/extRemes.pdf). An example of setting blocks to reduce complexity (from docs): `fit.blocks <- fevd(Prec, FortSub, threshold=0.395,
type="PP", units="inches", blocks = list(nBlocks = 100), verbose=TRUE)`

Comment: jessi   - Is the PP model equivalent to the GEV? The documentation says: "In the case of the PP model, block maxima of the data are calculated and the density of these block maxima are compared to the PP in terms of the equivalent GEV df."  So, based on this, the PP model is the equivalent of GEV? However, when I tried the following: superfit <- fevd(x=Gcomb, blocks = list(nBlocks = 2), type="PP"). I receive this error: Error in matrix(threshold, n, ncol(X.u), byrow = TRUE) : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL' Why would this be happening? Thanks

Comment: No pp is not the same as GEV. I think `extRemes` is allowing you different options for each approach. If you want to use blocks with `fevd`, you are using pp. It's been forever since I used this library. However, I think that if you really want to use GEV with your data in two blocks, you need to supply GEV only two sets of data. Therefore, you will need to use another function or series of functions until you have data in Year 1 to Year 7 and then Year 8 to Year 14.

Comment: jessi - thank you for this feedback. Yes, I would like to stick with the GEV. Therefore, under this approach, what if I just simply create a dataset that includes all annual maxima from Year 1 to Year 7, and then perform a GEV on that? And then create another dataset that includes all maxima for Year 8 to Year 14, and do a separate GEV on that?

Comment: I think that would satisfy what the function is expecting. I don’t know if it meets the needs of your research. Hope it works. If you are able to demonstrate it is reasonable, your final code with explanation will probably be helpful to others with your question. As an answer to your own question.

Comment: jessi - thanks, again! Yes, I will definitely do that and post back here as to this approach. And just one last thing - should I be assuming non-stationarity under this approach? If so, is there a way to define that using the fevd function? Thanks.